# Python Ctypes: OSError: exception: access violation reading <location>

Tags: c++, python-3.x, ctypes

I am trying to interface a CPP library with Python using Ctypes.

The cpp code I am trying to interface is available [here](https://github.com/ayan-b/geodesic_library).
All code used here is available [here](https://github.com/ayan-b/tvb-geodesic/tree/sof).

The python code that is used to interface is written in `gdist.py`.

`gdist.py`

```py
import ctypes
import glob
import os
import sys

import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse


if sys.platform == 'win32':
    libfile = glob.glob('build/*/gdist_c_api.dll')[0]
    libfile = os.path.abspath(libfile)
    lib = ctypes.CDLL(libfile)
elif sys.platform == 'darwin':
    libfile = glob.glob('build/*/gdist*.dylib')[0]
    lib = ctypes.CDLL(libfile)
else:
    libfile = glob.glob('build/*/gdist*.so')[0]
    lib = ctypes.CDLL(libfile)

lib.local_gdist_matrix.argtypes = [
    ctypes.c_uint,
    ctypes.c_uint,
    np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float64),
    np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.uint32),
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint),
    ctypes.c_double,
]
lib.local_gdist_matrix.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)

lib.free_memory.argtypes = [
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double),
]
lib.free_memory.restype = None


def local_gdist_matrix(
    vertices,
    triangles,
    max_distance=1e100,
):
    vertices = vertices.ravel()
    triangles = triangles.ravel()
    sparse_matrix_size = ctypes.c_uint(0)
    data = lib.local_gdist_matrix(
        vertices.size,
        triangles.size,
        vertices,
        triangles,
        ctypes.byref(sparse_matrix_size),
        max_distance,
    )
    np_data = np.fromiter(
        data,
        dtype=np.float64,
        count=3 * sparse_matrix_size.value,
    )
    lib.free_memory(data)
    assert np_data.size % 3 == 0
    sizes = np_data.size // 3
    rows = np_data[:sizes]
    columns = np_data[sizes: 2 * sizes]
    np_data = np_data[2 * sizes:]
    return scipy.sparse.csc_matrix(
        (np_data, (rows, columns)), shape=(vertices.size // 3, vertices.size // 3)
    )
```

`C++` code used to interface:

`gdist_c_api.h`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <inttypes.h>

#include "geodesic_algorithm_exact.h"


#if defined(_WIN32)
#  if defined(DLL_EXPORTS)
#    define DLL_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#    define DLL_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#  endif
#else
#  define DLL_EXPORT_API
#endif


double* local_gdist_matrix_impl(
    unsigned number_of_vertices,
    unsigned number_of_triangles,
    double *vertices,
    unsigned *triangles,
    unsigned *sparse_matrix_size,
    double max_distance
);

void free_memory_impl(double *ptr);

extern "C" {
    DLL_EXPORT_API double* local_gdist_matrix(
        unsigned number_of_vertices,
        unsigned number_of_triangles,
        double *vertices,
        unsigned *triangles,
        unsigned *sparse_matrix_size,
        double max_distance
    );

    DLL_EXPORT_API void free_memory(double *ptr);
};
```

`gdist_c_api.cpp`

```cpp
#include "gdist_c_api.h"


double* local_gdist_matrix_impl(
    unsigned number_of_vertices,
    unsigned number_of_triangles,
    double *vertices,
    unsigned *triangles,
    unsigned *sparse_matrix_size,
    double max_distance
) {
    std::vector<double> points (vertices, vertices + number_of_vertices);
    std::vector<unsigned> faces (triangles, triangles + number_of_triangles);
    
    geodesic::Mesh mesh;
    mesh.initialize_mesh_data(points, faces); // create internal mesh data structure including edges
    geodesic::GeodesicAlgorithmExact algorithm(&mesh); // create exact algorithm for the mesh
    std::vector <unsigned> rows_vector, columns_vector;
    std::vector <double> data_vector;

    double distance = 0;

    std::vector<geodesic::SurfacePoint> targets(number_of_vertices), source;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < number_of_vertices; ++i) {
        targets[i] = geodesic::SurfacePoint(&mesh.vertices()[i]);
    }
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < number_of_vertices / 3; ++i) {
        source.push_back(geodesic::SurfacePoint(&mesh.vertices()[i]));
        algorithm.propagate(source, max_distance, NULL);
        source.pop_back();
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < number_of_vertices / 3; ++j) {
            algorithm.best_source(targets[j], distance);
            if (distance != geodesic::GEODESIC_INF && distance != 0 && distance <= max_distance) {
                rows_vector.push_back(i);
                columns_vector.push_back(j);
                data_vector.push_back(distance);
            }
        }
    }

    double *data;
    data = new double[3 * rows_vector.size()];
    assert (data != NULL); // memory allocation should not fail
    *sparse_matrix_size = rows_vector.size();

    std::copy(rows_vector.begin(), rows_vector.end(), data);
    std::copy(columns_vector.begin(), columns_vector.end(), data + data_vector.size());
    std::copy(data_vector.begin(), data_vector.end(), data + 2 * data_vector.size());

    return data;
}


void free_memory_impl(double *ptr) {
    delete[] ptr;
}


extern "C" {
    double* local_gdist_matrix(
        unsigned number_of_vertices,
        unsigned number_of_triangles,
        double *vertices,
        unsigned *triangles,
        unsigned *sparse_matrix_size,
        double max_distance
    ) {
        return local_gdist_matrix_impl(
            number_of_vertices,
            number_of_triangles,
            vertices,
            triangles,
            sparse_matrix_size,
            max_distance
        );
    }

    void free_memory(double *ptr) {
        free_memory_impl(ptr);
    }
};
```

Batch script to create DLL file on Windows:

```
mkdir build\lib.win32
cd build\lib.win32
cl.exe /LD /DDLL_EXPORTS /EHsc /W4 ..\..\geodesic_library\gdist_c_api.cpp
```

Script to create `dylib` on macOS:

```sh
mkdir build
cd build
mkdir lib.macos
cd lib.macos
clang++ -std=c++11 -shared -fPIC ../../geodesic_library/gdist_c_api.cpp -o gdist_c_api.dylib
```

Test file:
`test_gdist.py`

```py
import numpy as np

import gdist


def test_equality_with_stable():
    surface_data = 'inner_skull_642'
    expected = np.loadtxt(f'data/{surface_data}/gdist_matrix.txt')
    vertices = np.loadtxt(
        f'data/{surface_data}/vertices.txt',
        dtype=np.float64,
    )
    triangles = np.loadtxt(
        f'data/{surface_data}/triangles.txt',
        dtype=np.uint32,
    )
    actual = gdist.local_gdist_matrix(
        vertices=vertices,
        triangles=triangles,
    )
    actual = actual.toarray()
    np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(actual, expected)

def test_flat_triangular_mesh():
    data = np.loadtxt("data/flat_triangular_mesh.txt", skiprows=1)
    vertices = data[0:121].astype(np.float64)
    triangles = data[121:].astype(np.uint32)
    distances = gdist.local_gdist_matrix(vertices, triangles)
    epsilon = 1e-6  # the default value used in `assert_array_almost_equal`
    # test if the obtained matrix is symmetric
    assert (abs(distances - distances.T) > epsilon).nnz == 0
    np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(distances.toarray()[1][0], 0.2)
    # set max distance as 0.3
    distances = gdist.local_gdist_matrix(vertices, triangles, 0.3)
    # test if the obtained matrix is symmetric
    assert (abs(distances - distances.T) > epsilon).nnz == 0
    assert np.max(distances) <= 0.3

def test_hedgehog_mesh():
    data = np.loadtxt("data/hedgehog_mesh.txt", skiprows=1)
    vertices = data[0:300].astype(np.float64)
    triangles = data[300:].astype(np.uint32)
    distances = gdist.local_gdist_matrix(vertices, triangles)
    epsilon = 1e-6  # the default value used in `assert_array_almost_equal`
    # test if the obtained matrix is symmetric
    assert (abs(distances - distances.T) > epsilon).nnz == 0
    np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(
        distances.toarray()[1][0], 1.40522
    )
    # set max distance as 1.45
    distances = gdist.local_gdist_matrix(vertices, triangles, 1.45)
    # test if the obtained matrix is symmetric
    assert (abs(distances - distances.T) > epsilon).nnz == 0
    assert np.max(distances) <= 1.45
```

If I run `pytest` on the code, the tests *sometimes* fail on Windows with the following error:

```sh
Windows fatal exception: access violation

Current thread 0x00001134 (most recent call first):

  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\gdist.py", line 92 in local_gdist_matrix
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\gdist.py", line 146 in local_gdist_matrix
  File "C:\Users\travis\build\ayan-b\tvb-geodesic\tests\test_gdist.py", line 64 in test_hedgehog_mesh
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 182 in pytest_pyfunc_call
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187 in _multicall
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84 in <lambda>
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93 in _hookexec
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286 in __call__
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py", line 1477 in runtest
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 135 in pytest_runtest_call
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187 in _multicall
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84 in <lambda>
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93 in _hookexec
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286 in __call__
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 217 in <lambda>
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 244 in from_call
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 216 in call_runtest_hook
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 186 in call_and_report
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 100 in runtestprotocol
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 85 in pytest_runtest_protocol
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187 in _multicall
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84 in <lambda>
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93 in _hookexec
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286 in __call__
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 272 in pytest_runtestloop
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187 in _multicall
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84 in <lambda>
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93 in _hookexec
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286 in __call__
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 247 in _main
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 191 in wrap_session
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 240 in pytest_cmdline_main
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187 in _multicall
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 84 in <lambda>
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93 in _hookexec
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286 in __call__
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 124 in main
  File "C:\Python38\Scripts\pytest.exe\__main__.py", line 7 in <module>
  File "c:\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 85 in _run_code
  File "c:\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 192 in _run_module_as_main
```

*Sometimes* it also fails on macOS with the following error:

```sh
tests/test_equality_with_stable.py Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x0000000103ce05c0 (most recent call first):

  File "/usr/local/bin/gdist.py", line 98 in local_gdist_matrix
  File "/usr/local/bin/gdist.py", line 151 in local_gdist_matrix
  File "/Users/travis/build/ayan-b/tvb-geodesic/tests/test_equality_with_stable.py", line 19 in test_equality_with_stable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/python.py", line 182 in pytest_pyfunc_call
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 187 in _multicall
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 87 in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 93 in _hookexec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 286 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/python.py", line 1477 in runtest
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 135 in pytest_runtest_call
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 187 in _multicall
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 87 in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 93 in _hookexec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 286 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 217 in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 244 in from_call
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 217 in call_runtest_hook
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 186 in call_and_report
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 100 in runtestprotocol
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 85 in pytest_runtest_protocol
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 187 in _multicall
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 87 in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 93 in _hookexec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 286 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 272 in pytest_runtestloop
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 187 in _multicall
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 87 in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 93 in _hookexec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 286 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 247 in _main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 191 in wrap_session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 240 in pytest_cmdline_main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 187 in _multicall
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 87 in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 93 in _hookexec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 286 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 125 in main
  File "/usr/local/bin/pytest", line 8 in <module>

/Users/travis/.travis/functions: line 109:  2197 Segmentation fault: 11  pytest --cov=gdist

The command "pytest --cov=gdist" exited with 139.
```

However, the tests never fail on Linux.

**Notes**:

- I am not sure if the issue is with the testing framework I am using. With
  `pytest` the test failed around 50% of the times however with `nose2` the test failed
  only once of 20+ runs.
  Log:

  - [Link](https://travis-ci.com/github/the-virtual-brain/tvb-gdist/jobs/356364643): Only once
    when `nose2` failed (on Windows).
  - [Link](https://travis-ci.com/github/ayan-b/tvb-geodesic/jobs/358274882): macOS with `pytest`
  - [Link](https://travis-ci.com/github/ayan-b/tvb-geodesic/jobs/358274883): Windows with `pytest`
- I have tried with both `CDLL` and `WinDLL` but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: So people are forced to download the whole repository? Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
for more asking related details. Also take a look at [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011) as they have the same outcome.

Comment: I have created a separate branch for this question with a lot of details removed. But a repo is till required to create the DLLs. Thus, unfortunately, it is not minimal by any means. I have also added the python file and cpp file that is used to interface.

Comment: @CristiFati I went through the linked post and it talks about the misspelling of `argtypes`, but I think I already have the correct spelling. I also think the argument types in the Python side is the same as the C side.

Comment: I noticed that after I posted the comment. I'm not sure about the difference of a "regular" *CTypes* pointer and a *NumPy* one (in the the *C* code they are the same, but *Python* wrapper handles them differently).

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks for the pointer! I did make some changes ([link](https://github.com/ayan-b/tvb-geodesic/commit/da5552162ffd7274ff831466184074724a62b772)) where I am using ctypes directly instead of numpy, however, the issue still persists.

Comment: Unfortunately I think you'll have to break the code and try to isolate and reproduce the problem outside that complex environment :( .